# pandas replace part of a column with another column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas data frame, let's call it `data`. `data` has two columns, column `a` and column `b`. Like this:

```
  a          b
0 aaa        tts
1 abb        tst
2 aba        tss
```

I would like to replace each `"a"` in column `a` with column `b`.Like this:

```
  a          b
0 ttsttstts tts
1 tstbb      tst
2 tssbtss    tss
```

I tied something like this :

```py
data['a'] = data['a'].apply(lambda x:x.replace("sub-string",data['b']))
```

but as I excepted, did not work. Could anyone please tell me what to do?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to iterate row-wise on the df (passing `axis=1`) so that you can access the individual 'b' column values that you intend to replace all occurrences of 'a' in the first column:

```
In [51]:
df['a'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['a'].replace('a',x['b']), axis=1)
df

Out[51]:
           a    b
0  ttsttstts  tts
1      tstbb  tst
2    tssbtss  tss
```

Comment: thanks so much this problem has bugged me for a long time and now my mind is finally at peace~~~

Comment: Sorry, i get an error: `TypeError: replace() argument 2 must be str, not float`